# Dump json string to unicode and parse it back

Tags: json, python-2.7

I'm trying to dump unicode string containting json to the value of another JSON, pass it as a json response to API and parse it back. It looks super-trivial but I'm stuck with it.

Here is a simplified code to reproduce.

```
>>> s = {u'k': '123213'}
>>> d = {1: unicode(s)}
>>> d
{1: u"{u'k': '123213'}"}
>>> d[1]
u"{u'k': '123213'}"
>>> json.loads(d[1])

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

How can I parse `d[1]` back to the valid json with python 2.7?

Comment: try this `json.loads(json.dumps(d[1]))`;

Comment: `unicode(s)` does _not_ produce [json](http://json.org/). json gets produced by `json.dumps(s)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ast` module

**Ex:**

```
>>> s = {u'k': '123213'}
>>> d = {1: unicode(s)}
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval(d[1])
{u'k': '123213'}
```

Comment: So, actually your answer helped me to understand, what was wrong. Thank you!